# wpf application with embedded database

Tags: wpf

I am a .net developer and I am looking forward to learn wpf. I don't want to use services to connect with a database. I want to use an embedded database.

Could anyone help me by providing me a tutorial or just to inform me of how could I start with my application as it concerned the database?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Look into [Sql Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The **BookLibrary** sample application of the [**WPF Application Framework (WAF)**](http://waf.codeplex.com) shows how to use the SQL Sever Compact in a WPF application.

Comment: This will help me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is also good :)